# Prove in Lean that ∀ i, 0 ≤ X i → ∃ i, X i > 1 → ∑ i, X i > 1

Tags: lean3, lean-mathlib

How to prove that if a term in a sum is > 1 then the sum is > 1?

```
universe x

variables
{ι : Type x} 
[fintype ι]
[decidable_eq ι]
(X : ι → ℝ)

example [∀ i, 0 ≤ X i] :
∃ i, X i > 1 → ∑ i, X i > 1 :=
begin
 sorry,
end
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: First, you should have a [MWE](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mwe.html) so it is easier for others to assist you.  In particular, your example should be "working" in that it includes the imports and has no errors.  In this case, you can add `import algebra.big_operators.basic data.real.basic` and `open_locale big_operators` to the top of your example.

Comment: Second, your theorem is actually false.  In Lean, (and most proof assistants), the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$ bind loosely, so you are actually asserting the existence of some `i` such that `X i > 1`.  Instead, use `example : (∀ i, 0 ≤ X i) → (∃ i, X i > 1) → ∑ i, X i > 1`.

Comment: I would also look in [algebra.big_operators.order](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/algebra/big_operators/order.html).  If (a more general version of) your theorem isn't there, at least you should be able to learn from the proofs to see what techniques you can use to prove your theorem.

Comment: But if you are still stuck and not getting answers here, I'd ask on the [Lean Zulip](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/) which gets more attention than this site (unfortunately).  But if you ask there, again give a MWE, explain what you have already tried, explain your reason for this lemma, link back to this question, and when you get an answer, post it here.

Comment: I think [finset.sum_le_sum_of_subset_of_nonneg](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/algebra/big_operators/order.html#finset.sum_le_sum_of_subset_of_nonneg) is a general version of your theorem.

Comment: Actually, maybe [`finset.single_le_sum`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/algebra/big_operators/order.html#finset.single_le_sum) is even more applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Gathering my comments into an answer.)  The theorem you are looking in `mathlib` under the name [finset.single_le_sum](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/algebra/big_operators/order.html#finset.single_le_sum):

```
theorem finset.single_le_sum {ι : Type u_1} {N : Type u_5} 
  [ordered_add_comm_monoid N] {f : ι → N} {s : finset ι}
  (hf : ∀ (i : ι), i ∈ s → 0 ≤ f i) {a : ι} (h : a ∈ s) :
f a ≤ s.sum (λ (x : ι), f x)
```

Depending on your use case, you probably can just use this theorem directly, but here is a proof of a working modification of your desired theorem:

```
import algebra.big_operators.basic data.real.basic algebra.big_operators.order

open_locale big_operators

universe x

variables
{ι : Type x} 
[fintype ι]
(X : ι → ℝ)

example (h : ∀ i : ι, 0 ≤ X i) (j : ι) (h1 : 1 < X j) : 1 < ∑ i : ι, X i :=
calc
  1   < X j      : h1
  ... ≤ ∑ i, X i : finset.single_le_sum (by simp [h]) (by simp)
                   -- simp tactic used to prove `(i : ι) ∈ finset.univ`
```

Here are also some notes:

- I found this theorem by first finding the [definition of the big operator `∑`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/algebra/big_operators/basic.html#finset.sum) and then exploring the other big operator files.  When I found [`algebra.big_operators.order`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/algebra/big_operators/order.html) it was clearly the right place since your theorem is true of most common totally ordered space which have addition (natural, integers, rationals, reals).
- Specifically, this theorem is not for the reals, but (as is common in `mathlib`) for a much more general case, namely `ordered_add_comm_monoid` which Lean knows the reals are an instance of.  (Specifically a commutative monoid is like a commutative group, but without necessarily an inverse. An ordered commutative monoid has a total order which "plays well" with the monoid operation.)
- The `mathlib` code doesn't explicitly have this theorem in the code.  Instead it has the version for products `∏`, namely [`finset.single_le_prod'`](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/3cf22a9150b86add043e8b5d14bc0be24f4ba091/src/algebra/big_operators/order.lean#L167).  But an additive monoid and a multiplicative monoid are the same save for the symbol they use for the monoid operator (and the big monoid operator).  So using the attribute `@[to_additive single_le_sum]` before the multiplicative theorem automatically generates the additive version of the theorem as well.
- You don't need to explicitly give `[decidable_eq ι]`.  That could either be because it is not needed to prove this, or because it is already proved and used in previous lemmas through the axiom of choice (which is used freely in `mathlib` without reservation).
- The largest difference between your example and the theorem in `mathlib` is that the `mathlib` version uses a generic `s : finset ι` whereas you use `finset.univ`. (Note, `∑ i : ι, X i` is syntactic sugar for `∑ i in finset.univ, X i`.)  So when filling in the parameters of the theorem, I used `by simp` to automatically prove that `i ∈ finset.univ` for all `i : ι` when needed.  (It was an educated guess that this fact would be a `simp` lemma.)